# Updating JSP when a client side file changes

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I am working on a project which has two parts:

a) Java Application running on a client machine.
b) Web Application hosted on a web server.

The Java Application produces some results after a random interval of time. These results  need to be reflected on the webpage/JSP using the javascript method in it say every 5 seconds so that it is up to date.

Could you please suggest some approach.

I believe that the java application doesn't require to send any request to the server side. Instead if it could write to a local file which the javascript method in the JSP would constantly monitor for changes and update the JSP with the contents, it would do the trick. But I don't know if that's feasible and if it is, how it needs to be done.

Also the WebApplication should be supported in both IE and Firefox.

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach of monitoring a file on the filesystem with javascript is not the way to go. It would be much better, if you split the task in half:

1) A simple page, which displays the *current* file. That would be possible through simple polling via the *setTimeout()*-Function 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

commonly implemented in the form:

```
var myApp={};
var fiveSecondsInterval=5000;
var myApp.pollServer=function(){ setTimeOut(function(){ 
/* retrieve the current data */
if(conditionIsNotMet) myApp.pollServer();
}, fiveSecondsInterval)}
```

Hence some condition isn't met, myApp.poll will call itself at an interval of five seconds.

2) The endpoint on the server, where you hold your data. So everytime, this endpoint is called, the page serves the current content/data of the file.

A much more complex solution would include *server push technology* http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Ajax

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-cometjava/

Comment: I understand what you mean and have successfully implemented it using Long Polling. But just for awareness I'd like to know what is wrong in the approach that I suggested. Thank You.

Comment: "Instead if it could write to a local file which the javascript method in the JSP would constantly monitor for changes and update the JSP with the contents, it would do the trick." There is no way for Javascript in the browser to watch the local filesystem. It would be a security risk. On the other hand, if you tell a server via Java/Jsp to serve a file, one can assume, that you intended to do such a thing.